# Remove occurances of ",,," from MySQL Database Output PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, text-files

I am outputting the contents of my MySQL Database into a text file using the below code:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'myusername';
$pass = 'mypassword';
$db = 'mydbname';
$table = 'mytablename';
$file = 'outputfilename';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
//$csv_output .= $row['Field']."; ";
$i++;
}
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table."");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
$csv_output .= $rowr[$j].",";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}
//echo $csv_output;
$myFile = "output.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $csv_output;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
exit;
?>
```

However I would like to know how I could replace the occurances of the string `",,,"` with this: `","` before it goes into the text file.

Comment: are you concerned about more than three?  Or two?  `,,,,,,,,,` will be turned into `,,,`.  Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Something like this (untested):

```
$pattern = '/\,\,\,/';
$replacement = ',';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $stringData);
```

Comment: `,` is not a meta-character, and as such there's no need to escape it.  The pattern `/,,,/` should work the same.

Answer (score 4):

No need for `preg_replace()`.

A simple [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) will suffice.

```
$stringData = str_replace(',,,', ',', $csv_output);
```

Comment: @Matt Ball `preg_replace` is a bit of an overkill in here, isn't it? :)

Comment: yes, `str_replace()` is better in this case. But - I'm not a PHP guy, so it wasn't the answer I thought of.

Answer (score 3):

problem is in:

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table."");
```

if you got `,,,,` it means that some columns has no value. Detect those columns, do not include them in `SELECT` statement.

if you will automatically (preg_replace, str_replace) change multiple commas to one comma, you are on good way to corrupt CSV file.

Comment: Agreed with the comment about CSV file corruption.

Comment: @XcodeDev - any multiple commas (even 2) automatic change to one comma may couse CSV corruption

Comment: I have decided to change it to the following ",n/a," rather than just one comma.

Comment: CSV (comma separated values) - if got "value1,,value3" means that value2 is empty - you do not need to change anything - file will be read correctly - if nice visual reprentation of "n/a" is needed - go ahead and do it - it your script

Answer (score 1):

add this code:

```
while ($csv_output=str_replace(',,', ',', $csv_output)) echo '.';
```

OR change the for code:

```
for ( $j=0; $j<$i; $j++) {
    $csv_output .= (isset($rowr[$j])) ? $rowr[$j]."," : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()`

```
$stringData = str_replace(',,,', ',', $stringData);
```

http://php.net/str-replace